# Angular form is valid with unselected select

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have an Angular form that has a select, which is marked as required.

When the form loads, a *Choose a region* message is shown to prompt the user to make a selection.

However, the form is valid even if it does not have a valid selection.

If the user selects a valid option, then selects *Choose a Region* the form validation marks the form as invalid.

Why is the form not invalid to start with?

**Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="region" 
            ng-model="regionId"
            ng-options="region.id as region.name for region in regions" 
            ng-selected="region.id"
            required>
      <option value="">-- choose a region --</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var myRegions = [{ id: 1, name: "England" }, 
                   { id: 2, name: "Wales" }, 
                   { id: 3, name: "Northern Ireland" }, 
                   { id: 4, name: "Scotland" }
                  ];
  $scope.regions = myRegions;
  $scope.regionId = 0;
}
```

Here is the code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgjertsen/65e5vj5r/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form is valid because you set initial value `$scope.regionId = 0;`. Just remove it or replace on `$scope.regionId = "";`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/zyecywr1/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    var myRegions = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "England"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Wales"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "Northern Ireland"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "Scotland"
    }];
    vm.regions = myRegions;
    vm.regionId = "";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <form name="myForm">
      isValid: {{myForm.$valid}}
      <br>
      <select name="region" ng-model="vm.regionId" ng-options="region.id as region.name for region in vm.regions" ng-selected="vm.region.id" required>
        <option value="">-- choose a region --</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I knew I had missed something obvious!

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider `$pristine` property of the form. See the working example below:

```js
angular.module("test", []).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  var myRegions = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "England"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Wales"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Northern Ireland"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Scotland"
  }];
  $scope.regions = myRegions;
  $scope.regionId = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="region" ng-model="regionId" ng-options="region.id as region.name for region in regions" ng-selected="region.id" required>
      <option value="">-- choose a region --</option>
    </select>
    
  </form>
  
  <p ng-bind="regionId"></p>
  
  <hr>
  <span ng-show="!myForm.$pristine && myForm.$valid">Form Valid</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.$pristine || myForm.$invalid">Form Invalid</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, the code sample was cut back for demo purposes.

Comment: Okay, I didn't looked at the actual cause.

Answer (score 0):

Required works when it comes to *form-submission*..

If you put a **submit button**, Your form would **no longer return valid** status... and you can do that using `ng-submit` attribute in your form tag which will be fired by your

```
<input type="submit">
```

Or you can simply keep the first option that you have added to your select as

```
  <option value="" disabled>-- choose a region --</option>
```

This disabled won't allow it to return empty value.

Moreover if you want to test the submit form thing, run the snippet below.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  var myRegions = [
    { id: 1, name: "England" }, 
      { id: 2, name: "Wales" }, 
      { id: 3, name: "Northern Ireland" }, 
      { id: 4, name: "Scotland" }
      ];
  $scope.regions = myRegions;
  $scope.regionId = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="region" 
            ng-model="regionId"
            ng-options="region.id as region.name for region in regions" 
            ng-selected="region.id"
            required>
      <option value="">-- choose a region --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <p ng-bind="regionId"></p>
  <hr>
  <span ng-show="myForm.$valid">Form Valid</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.$invalid">Form Invalid</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I have a submit button on the full page, which doesn't work.

Comment: But is that submit button out of the form tag or inside the form tag?

Comment: And i also gave another solution to solve your problem. @KarlGjertsen

Comment: Adding disabled stops the first item being selected, which is the point of having it there.

Comment: This would make sure that no empty value would be passed through the form..

Comment: But you would be forcing a selection, not forcing the user to select.
Adding a button does not fix this issue.

Comment: Alright @KarlGjertsen Its alright to remove disabled from option but I also added a snippet where you can see that it won't let the form status stay valid if the unselected select is submitted.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work. I tried it in the fiddler example, which has been updated, and it doesn't work.